# startActivity() gets called by android system_process infinite times

Tags: android, android-intent, android-emulator

Problem:-
startActivity() gets called by android  **system_process** infinite times. so The code below opens the  **MainActivity**  but then the MainActivity get freezed/hanged and after several minutes android shut itself down.

I have two Activities:

1. RegisterActivity
2. MainActivity

After registeration process completed , i want to redirect the user to home screen (i.e.MainActivity) so i use this code to start the activity:--

```
Button btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);  
    }
});
```

But the startActivity() gets called infinite times by android system. I figured out this by Logcat. The logcat output is:--

```
03-20 10:08:25.756: I/ActivityManager(63): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.techdeedapps.fallonmoving/.MainActivity }
03-20 10:08:25.826: W/InputManagerService(63): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@44c7f1b0 (uid=10026 pid=316)
03-20 10:08:25.826: W/InputManagerService(63): Client not active, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@44c4ef28
03-20 10:08:25.966: I/ActivityManager(63): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.techdeedapps.fallonmoving/.MainActivity }
03-20 10:08:26.036: W/InputManagerService(63): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@44c7f1b0 (uid=10026 pid=316)
03-20 10:08:26.036: W/InputManagerService(63): Client not active, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@44c28e48
03-20 10:08:26.176: I/ActivityManager(63): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.techdeedapps.fallonmoving/.MainActivity }
03-20 10:08:26.246: W/InputManagerService(63): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@44c7f1b0 (uid=10026 pid=316)
03-20 10:08:26.246: W/InputManagerService(63): Client not active, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@44c11b98
03-20 10:08:26.396: I/ActivityManager(63): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.techdeedapps.fallonmoving/.MainActivity }
03-20 10:08:26.437: D/dalvikvm(316): GREF has increased to 201
03-20 10:08:26.606: I/ActivityManager(63): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.techdeedapps.fallonmoving/.MainActivity }
03-20 10:08:26.676: W/InputManagerService(63): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@44c7f1b0 (uid=10026 pid=316)
03-20 10:08:26.676: W/InputManagerService(63): Client not active, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@44de2330
03-20 10:08:26.816: I/ActivityManager(63): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.techdeedapps.fallonmoving/.MainActivity }
03-20 10:08:26.826: E/SurfaceFlinger(63): createSurface() failed, generateId = -12
03-20 10:08:26.826: W/WindowManager(63): OutOfResourcesException creating surface
03-20 10:08:26.826: I/WindowManager(63): Out of memory for surface!  Looking for leaks...
03-20 10:08:26.826: W/WindowManager(63): No leaked surfaces; killing applicatons!
03-20 10:08:26.826: W/ActivityManager(63): Killing processes for memory at adjustment 0
03-20 10:08:26.826: W/ActivityManager(63): Killing for memory: ProcessRecord{44f32af0 316:com.techdeedapps.fallonmoving/10026} (adj 0)
03-20 10:08:26.826: I/Process(63): Sending signal. PID: 316 SIG: 9
03-20 10:08:26.836: W/WindowManager(63): Looks like we have reclaimed some memory, clearing surface for retry.
03-20 10:08:26.836: W/WindowManager(63): Due to memory failure, waiting a bit for next layout
03-20 10:08:26.856: I/ActivityManager(63): Process com.techdeedapps.fallonmoving (pid 316) has died.
03-20 10:08:27.176: I/WindowManager(63): WIN DEATH: Window{44fac7d8 com.techdeedapps.fallonmoving/com.techdeedapps.fallonmoving.MainActivity paused=false}
03-20 10:08:27.196: I/WindowManager(63): WIN DEATH: Window{44faa318 com.techdeedapps.fallonmoving/com.techdeedapps.fallonmoving.MainActivity paused=false}
```

MainActivity code:

```
     public class MainActivity extends Activity {
AlertDialog.Builder builder;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    Button btnEnter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEnter);
    btnEnter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (RegisterActivity.loggedIn) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        AddActivity.class));
            } else {
                Utility.showAlertDialog(builder, "Please Log In!");
            }
        }

    Button btnSettings = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSettings);
    btnSettings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    RegisterActivity.class));
        }
    });

}
```

RegisterActivity code:

```
    public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register);
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    etName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etName);
    etEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
    Button btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
    btnsubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,
                    MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
    }
}
```

this logcat output is continous till i close the emulator!And if i dont close the emulator then android restarts automatically. simply the **system hangs cause it infinitely calls the startActivity()!**

Comment: post more code. I'd guess you are calling performClick in loop or something. Or it is in your HomeActivity

Comment: Try removing the finish()

Comment: please post complete code of register activity

Comment: can we so your FULL CODE of both Activity????

Comment: i removed the finish() but not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually its my fault ..! startActivity() gets called infinitely cause when i finish the activity i was again start it another activity!..But I appreciate all the responders for their kind help.Thank you very much..!